# $DFA/NFA$ for $L(OPPOSITE)=\{uv:vu\in L\}$

Tags: automata, regular-language

I'm trying to prove that: $L(OPPOSITE)=\{uv:vu\in L\} \in L_{FA}$ given that: $L \in L_{FA}$ .
I'm trying to construct a finite automata that accepts $L(OPPOSITE)$ in order to prove it but I got stuck.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572401/working-with-the-word-wy-while-given-the-word-yw

Comment: @hhsaffar Thank you, I read it but the solution there is not that clear to me..

Comment: <http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/prove-that-regular-languages-are-closed-under-the-cycle-operator>

Comment: @portin.daniel Thanks for the reference!